# Parity of the order of a element

Tags: elliptic-curves, number-theory, pohlig-hellman

Given an element $g$ in a cyclic group $G$ of *known* order $m$ its easy to test if $g$ has even or odd order. In other words $\textrm{ord}(g) \bmod 2$ can be computed easily.

In some cases where the order of the group is *unknown* it is also easy to test if $g$ has even order for a large subset of $g$ in $G$.

For example, if $g$ is an element in ${\mathbb{Z}_n}^*$ and the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{g}{n}\right)$ is $-1$ then $g$ has even order. (If it is $1$ then we can't say anything.)

What other examples are there of cryptographically interesting groups $G$ where it is easy to test if $g$ has even order (or odd order) for a large subset of $g$ in $G$?

Comment: From this: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/151, such an easy test exists for the class groups of supersingular elliptic curves for $p\equiv 1\mod 4$.